# NodeJs - Fluent-FFMPEG cannot find FFMPEG

Tags: node.js

Situation:

Run mp3-to-video with fluent-ffmpeg and ffmpeg on windows and nodejs.
command used to startup server: nodemon server.js
When starting up, it executes mp3-to-video function. Then calls fluent-ffmpeg and i debugged it down to the line where fluent-ffmpeg cannot find my ffmpeg package.
I did add a couple of system variables. FFMPEG_PATH is included, PATH is included, and all the different directories like ffmpeg\ and ffmpeg\lib\

I dont know what to do..
I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot findd ffmpeg
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:136:22
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:123:9
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:421:16
    at next (C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5302:29)
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:906:16
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:116:11
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\utils.js:223:16
    at F (C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\which\which.js:68:16)
    at E (C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    at C:\Users\lexha\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
```

Comment: I had the same error on linux. I solved it with `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

EvilBurrito saved the day on this one.
Just wanted to add, make sure use this require:

```js
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
```

Comment: Thank you! lots of headaches with this problem.

Answer (score 49):

You could perhabs install this node module "ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg". You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg

It will install ffmpeg on your system and node should be able to use it immediately.

Hope this answer helps you and other people :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try install the package by running

`npm i @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg`